# Inserting multivalues from textbox into the MySQL Database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, multivalue

I'm having a problem with my PHP and MySQL project . I wanted to insert multi collumn value into the database but the truth is, im already confused by the codes. it's like this if you would like to take a look:

```
    if(!empty($_POST['brando'])){
        $A="brand = '$brando'";}
        else{
        $A=" ";}    

    if(!empty($_POST['prnameo'])){
        $B="product_name = '$prnameo'";}
        else{
        $B=" ";}    

    if(!empty($_POST['prido'])){
        $C="product_id = '$prido'";}
        else{
        $C=" ";}    

    if(!empty($_POST['prcolo'])){
        $D="color = '$prcolo'";}    
        else{
        $D=" ";}    

    if(!empty($_POST['priceo'])){
        $E="price = '$priceo'";}
        else{
        $E=" ";}    



        $sqlq="UPDATE $tbl_name2 SET $A $B $C $D $E  where id='$id'";


        mysql_query($sqlq);
```

I noticed that querying multivalue command into a database requires comma such as:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE $tablename SET collumn1='value', collum2='value' where id='value'");
```

and now i cant put any comma or "," in any of those codes, making the PHP page unable to send other variable values into the server.

even if i change the coding to this:

```
$sqlq="UPDATE $tbl_name2 SET $A , $B , $C , $D , $E  where id='$id'";
```

it'll produce what else but damn errors.

so i would like to ask for help if you know what i'm talking about. i know, it sounds like i've been stressed out by the codings.

ooh, this code too, i forgot to put it for these.

```
    for ($help_given=1, $help_given++)
    {
    echo "Thanks";
    }
```

Comment: Just FYI: Your script is prone to sql injections.

Comment: What does `echo $sqlq` give you?

Comment: @TimWolla sql injection is something that i'm ignoring because these are supposedly to finish up my final project and it runs on localhost. i know im new with php and stuff, but sql injections are not my focus.

Comment: @jprofitt echo $sqlq; = "UPDATE product_list SET brand = 'test' product_name = 'test' product_id = 'test' color = 'test' price = '0.001' where id='1' "

Comment: @Rfq sql injections are something one should not easily ignore, even on local projects. You better do it always the right way and don't run into problems lateron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to implode() an array with "," ，like this:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['brando'])){
    $value[] ="brand = '$brando'";
}

if(!empty($_POST['prnameo'])){
    $value[] ="product_name = '$prnameo'";
}

if(!empty($_POST['prido'])){
    $value[] ="product_id = '$prido'";
}

if(!empty($_POST['prcolo'])){
    $value[] ="color = '$prcolo'";
}

if(!empty($_POST['priceo'])){
    $value[] ="price = '$priceo'";
}

$sqlq="UPDATE $tbl_name2 SET " . implode(",",$value)."  where id='$id'";
mysql_query($sqlq);
?>
```

Then, you'd better to use "mysql_escape_string" or "PDO::prepare" method to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: this one looks promising although to tell you the truth, i dont know those php method such as "mysql_escape_string" "implode" or even "prepare". i'll try that, once the result is good or otherwise, i'll inform you. thanks a lot, dude.

Comment: i wish i could vote this up, but i dont have enough reputation. but still, you solved it, dude. i couldnt thank you enough but still, i appreciate it. thanks a lot.

Comment: It’s my pleasure. @Rfqkml please remind that **unset/empty** $value[] at the beginning of this section, otherwise you may got an unexpected result :P

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(isset($_POST['brando']))
    {
        $brando=mysql_escape_string($_POST['brando']);
        $A="brand = ".$brando;
    }
    else
    {
        $A=" ";
    }


    if(isset($_POST['prnameo']))
    {
        $prnameo=mysql_escape_string($_POST['prnameo']);
        $B="product_name = ".$prnameo;
    }
    else
    {
        $B=" ";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['prido']))
    {
        $prido=mysql_escape_string($_POST['prido']);
        $C="product_id = ".$prido;
    }
    else
    {
        $C=" ";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['prcolo']))
    {
        $prcolo=mysql_escape_string($_POST['prcolo']);
        $D="color= ".$prcolo;
    }
    else
    {
        $D=" ";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['priceo']))
    {
        $priceo=mysql_escape_string($_POST['priceo']);
        $E="price = ".$brando;
    }
    else
    {
        $E=" ";
    }

    $tbl_name="mytable";//to set
    $id='primary_key';//to set

    $sqlq="UPDATE $tbl_name SET $A, $B, $C, $D, $E  where id='$id'";

    mysql_query($sqlq);
```

Just put values where I have commented as //to set...

Comment: can you explain to me what's the function of mysql_excape_string? reading the explanation "Returns the escaped string, or FALSE on error. " and "If this function is not used to escape data, the query is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attacks. " doesnt seem to fill my head with adequate information.

Comment: oh hmm ok but where should i put the comma?

i mean, in here:
$A="brand = '$brando',";}

or here:
$sqlq="UPDATE $tbl_name2 SET $A , $B , $C , $D , $E  where id='$id'";

because im not sure it will run effectively.

Comment: $sqlq="UPDATE $tbl_name2 SET $A , $B , $C , $D , $E  where id='$id'";

Comment: ok i'll try those. once i get the result, i'll give the feedback. thanks.